# Return v1 vector from another function in javascript (Accessing variables from other functions)

Tags: javascript

I currently have this code and it creates two vectors, v1 and v2. I'm new to Javascript and not sure to return it so it's accessible within another function so I can say alert(v1) or v1.add in a different function.

```
function handleDrawEvent() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    //initializing new vector to all zeros
    //red vector
    let v1 = new Vector3();
    v1.v = [0, 0, 0]

    //blue vector
    let v2 = new Vector3();
    v2.v = [0, 0, 0]

    //z coordinate not being used (2d vector)
    //grab the value from the input HTML and convert it to a number
    v1.v[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v1-x").value);
    v1.v[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v1-y").value);

    v2.v[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v2-x").value);
    v2.v[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v2-y").value);
    //call drawVector(v1, "red"); given 
    drawVector(v1, "red");
    drawVector(v2, "blue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can't be used outside the scope of the function, if you need to use it outside can do something like:

```js
let v1, v2; //Here you set your variables to be used in any function;

function handleDrawEvent() {
    //initializing new vector to all zeros
    //red vector
    v1 = new Vector3();
    v1.v = [0, 0, 0]

    //blue vector
    v2 = new Vector3();
    v2.v = [0, 0, 0]
}

function useVectors() {
     console.log(v1, v2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a return statement at the end of handleDrawEvent function like so :

```js
return [v1,v2]
```

then you can call handleDrawEvent (it will run all the code of the function before returning)

```js
let myVectors = handleDrawEvent()
let v1 = myVectors[0]
let v2 = myVectors[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put v1 and v2 outside the function:

```js
let v1 = new Vector3();
let v2 = new Vector3();

// Then you can use on many functions as you want:
function handleDrawEvent() {
    // some code here

    //initializing new vector to all zeros
    //red vector
    v1.v = [0, 0, 0]

    //blue vector
    v2.v = [0, 0, 0]

    // The rest of your code here...
}

function anotherFunction() {
    alert(v1);
    alert(v2);
}
```